# Different color of TextInputLayout outline color when enable=true then black and enable false than light gray

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I'm using `TextInputLayout`, As our need I want to change color of outline when **`enable=true`** and gray color for when **`enable=false`**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/state_text_input"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ue the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) in the [Material Component Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and use the **`app:boxStrokeColor`** attribute in your layout.

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color"
    ...>
```

You can use a selector. It is the default value:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```